# Is there a way to read and write on multiple text files in a folder using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve several text files from a folder. Afterwards, I am trying to read all of the files within the directory to which I then append a blank line at the top of each file.

However, once I run the program it does not execute what I desire. This is the code:

```
import os

folderPath = "./textFiles"


def myFilesAddEmptyLine():
    for file in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(file, "r+") as myFile:
                # print(myFile)
                # ^ This returns "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r+' encoding='cp1252'>" in the console.
                fileContent = myFile.read()
                myFile.seek(0, 0)
                myFile.write("\n" + fileContent)


myFilesAddEmptyLine()
```

On the other hand, if I read the file directly without trying to automate the process using **os**, it executes what I am trying to achieve flawlessly. Therefore, the following piece of code opens the file and appends a blank line at the top of the file.

```
def myFilesAddEmptyLine():
    with open("test.txt", "r+") as myFile:
        fileContent = myFile.read()
        myFile.seek(0, 0)
        myFile.write("\n" + fileContent)

myFilesAddEmptyLine()
```

Could anyone kindly outline what the issue with the first piece of code is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It runs without any problem in my computer. Maybe you can put more context in your post. If an error happens what is it etc.

Comment: I'm wondering if an explicit 'file close' would be needed.  https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python ; so that would be myFile.Close() once you have written the extra line.

Comment: @Asocia the runtime does not return any errors. It simply does not append the blank line at the top.

Comment: @asylumax To my knowledge, the with automatically closes the file by itself.

Comment: @RobertCassarPace I see. As I said, it runs as expected in my computer so you can be sure that there is nothing wrong with your code. I run it couple of times and 3-4 blank lines appeared in the `.txt` files.

Comment: Ran on my machine, but I had to put a with "open(os.path.join(folderPath, file), "r+") as myFile:" there.

Comment: Thanks @asylumax, that was it! I ran it and it worked as I wanted to! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, this must be the problem. I set the `folderPath = "."` since I don't have such directory but you need to give full path of course.

Comment: Great; I'm wondering why it didn't throw an error for you; that's what happened for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @asylumax pointed out in the comments, this:

```
import os

folderPath = "./textFiles"

def myFilesAddEmptyLine():
    for file in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(file, "r+") as myFile:
                fileContent = myFile.read()
                myFile.seek(0, 0)
                myFile.write("\n" + fileContent)

myFilesAddEmptyLine()
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
import os

folderPath = "./textFiles"

def myFilesAddEmptyLine():
    for file in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(os.path.join(folderPath, file), "r+") as myFile: #This is the line that needed changing.
                fileContent = myFile.read()
                myFile.seek(0, 0)
                myFile.write("\n" + fileContent)
                print(myFile)

myFilesAddEmptyLine()
```